# Showing Album Art in Windows 8 Media Control

Tags: javascript, windows-8, uri, media

I am trying to add the Album art for Windows 8 Media Controls in JS

I have the following code that is not working:

```
Windows.Media.MediaControl.albumArt = "http://www.someimagesite.com/image1.jpg";
```

I know that the MediaControl.albumArt doest support strings but rather URI's but I am inexperenced with JS and URI's and wondering if anyone knows if i can easily input a URI from a url string into the about situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Windows.Foundation.Uri class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.uri.aspx).  For example ...

```
var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("ms-appdata:///mycontent/" + fileName); 
mediaControls.albumArt = uri;
```

Check out [this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Buttons-ea57d8e2).

Answer (score 0):

[Straight from the horse's mouth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.mediacontrol.albumart):

> If you provide an invalid path for the album art property, it will cause an exception to be thrown. The only valid URI formats are ms-appx:// and ms-appdata://.

Essentially you can not point to the image located on the web. You should have album art shipped as part of you application package or you should load image from the web, save it to your app's local storage and then assign albumArt to something like `ms-appdata://mylocalimage.jpg`

Comment: Is there any examples of this you can show? From URL to local, im needing it again (just used static app logo last time as i gave up) and now need it for live tiles :)